# Split String using delimiter by delimiter count in java

Tags: java, delimiter

I have a data looks like:

> 4819116|2014-12-25T06:45:42|24.4153|-109.0765

`int|yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS|int| -ve int`

I want to split as:

`4819116, 2014, 12, 25, 06:45:42, 24.4153, -109.0765`

when i use delimiter as: `String col [] = line.split("[|T-]");`

It reads negative number as positive(i.e,`-109.0765` as `109.0765`) but I want to read as negative. i.e, I want to use `-` delimiter only 2 times.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to split on `-` only if it is surrounded by digits.

In that case use `split("[|T]|(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)")`

`(?<=\\d)` and `(?=\\d)` are [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms

DEMO:

```
String data = "4819116|2014-12-25T06:45:42|24.4153|-109.0765";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data.split("[|T]|(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)")));
```

Output: `[4819116, 2014, 12, 25, 06:45:42, 24.4153, -109.0765]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line.split("([|T]|(?<![|])-)")` which will `split` on "|" or "T" or "-" not preceded by a "|".